# Processing Zip file in Apex code (Server side Zip processing)

Tags: apex

As the title suggest. We need to process zip file in Apex code to perform some tasks which are completely depend on Zip file.

Because the data is confidential so we don't want is to process on client side. So is there any way to process Zip file in Apex? Some library or custom approach we could use. Also I have a doubt that if Zip file can be processed, will it within the governor limit of Salesforce?

I have searched everywhere but couldn't found any solution. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this natively in Apex using the Zippex library which is open source. https://github.com/pdalcol/Zippex

Comment: Undoubtedly this is needed. Thanks for share! However having this natively has limitation of heap size. Did you check how much memory it uses while compression or decompression? I have been exploring zip solutions for 3 years. Governor limits are real challenge.

Comment: @Ashwani zipping and unzipping is expensive on heap size and CPU time. My initial focus was on CPU optimizations but I have some ideas to reduce heap usage that I will implement in future releases of Zippex. Meanwhile you can get higher limits by running your code asynchronously. If that is not enough, you can get even higher limits using @future(limits='3xHeap') or @future(limits='3xCPU') or by chaining Queueable jobs. Also remember to nullify any large variables as soon as you are done using them.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this blog post from Andrew Fawcett - this utilises the built in zip handling that Salesforce provides for static resources:

http://andyinthecloud.com/2012/11/04/handling-office-files-and-zip-files-in-apex-part-1/

Comment: Thank you. Actually, It works client side but I need processing server side completely. I have seen this post. This was the only solution I could found. (+1)

Comment: The first part of the blog post gives a mechanism for processing server side - if the user uploads a zip, you can use the apex metadata library to store it as a static resource and then extract the files as you need.